# Is there a way in python to start a Powershell "session" / pass multiple commands at different times to a single powershell session?

Tags: python, subprocess

For example, let's say I wanted to set a variable in powershell (or command line), and then get that variable later using something like subprocess.check_output("echo $var", shell=True) (this isn't something I need to do, just an example). Or, lets say I wanted to have a user 'cd' to a directory, and be able to run commands from that directory. I would be able to have some python variable that saves the current directory, and always run "cd {dir};{command}", but that would be inefficient, and still wouldn't work for every situation, I would need to add some special bit of code for every possible situation where a user could want to run a command, then run another command which depends on the first command.

Sorry if I phrased this question badly, let me know if I should clarify. TIA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after some searching, I found a way to do this. Using a module called pexpect, MarkBaggett on GitHub has made a simple way to do this: [pxpowershell](https://gist.github.com/MarkBaggett/a7c10195b2626c78009bf73bcdb6db20). here's an example:

```
ps = pxpowershell()
ps.start_process()
ps.run("$x = 10")
print(ps.run("echo $x"))
ps.stop_process()
```

The only small problems are that 1. colors don't work, and 2. you need to decode() and strip() the output, though you can just add that into the pxpowershell.py.